# Displaying Data from JSON using AJAX call

Tags: ajax

Here is my json file(list.js)

```
{
    "loginid":"Wafiqa",
    "password":"123"
}
```

Here is my html file(ajaxTest.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Username:</p>
    <div id="uname"></div>
    <p>Password:</p>
    <div id="pword"></div>

    <script>
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        datatype:"json",
        async:false,
        url:'ref/list.js',
        success:function(data){
            alert(data.loginid);
        },
        error:function(jqXHR,textStatus){
        errorHandling(textStatus);
        }

    });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

What I want to do is. I want to display the user id and password from the json file in `div id="uname"` and `div id="pword"`. How can I do that?

Comment: In the code sample above your `<div>` has id="uname" but in the text below you have id="username".

Answer (score 0):

```
success:function(data){
    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(data);
    $('div#uname').text(jsonObj.loginid);
    $('div#pword').text(jsonObj.password);
},
```

Comment: uname defined as id, change to this `$('div#uname')`

Comment: Can you do a simple `alert(data)` and see what you get?  Let's try to find out if your GET request is even returning correctly.  You can also try accessing `ref/list.js` directly from your browser address bar and see if you open a page containing your JSON.

Comment: Yes i can access the json data from the browser..but how can I do the alert data?

Comment: Inside your `success` function add the following line: `alert(data)`.  A dialog box should open up.  If it doesn't contain the JSON text you expect, we know something is wrong.

Comment: The dialog box didn't appear.. it should be alert(data); isn't it?

Comment: Last comment: Open your JavaScript console in your broswer and see what is happening with your request.  [Here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) is a page which will tell you how to do this.  Good luck!

Comment: I had open it..it display `Uncaught ReferenceError: errorHandling is not defined`

Comment: Aha!  So let's just delete `errorHandling` for right now.  So your `error:function` should be empty for the moment.  Try again and let us know what happens.

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because they don't teach the solution.

Comment: I cannot find the solution yet.

Comment: @NurWafiqa You need to see what is happening when you issue your AJAX call.  If nothing is coming back, it probably means that your URL is wrong and needs to be changed.  And please change the name of your JSON file to "list.json".  The `.js` extension should be reserved for JavaScript source files.

Comment: Okay.. I try to fix that

Comment: But the console.log display the value from the json..only the popup didn't show and the div

Comment: Debug every piece of the success function until you find out where things are going wrong.  This question is mess now.

Comment: I'm sorry Tim.I really stuck in Ajax..So sorry

Comment: Connect with me on LinkedIn [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pub/tim-biegeleisen/8/aa3/557) and we can exchange emails.  Too many comments already.  Once you solve it, I will re-post my answer to clean things up.  Don't touch your original posting.

Answer (score 0):

For all beginners, here are the answer for your reference

Username:

Password:

```
    <script>
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        datatype:"json",
        async:false,
        url:'ref/list.json',
        success:function(data){
        alert("Welcome "+data.password+data.loginid);
        console.log(data.password);

    $('#uname').html(data.loginid);
    $('#pword').html(data.password);
}

    });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```